# La opción -c requiere privilegios administrativos al hacer ping

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero saber las ip activas en mi red y para ello estoy haciendo ping en un rango de direcciones, pero no me deja.Dice que requiere de privilegios administrativos. Alguien sabria¿Alguien sabría como solucionarlo?.

Les dejo el código por si es de utilidad:

```
import subprocess
import os

for ip in range(255):
    ipAddres='192.168.1.'+str(ip)
    respuesta=os.system("ping -c 1 "+ipAddres)
    if respuesta:
        print(ipAddres)
```

Sistema operativo: Windows 10.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres usar el argumento `-c`? Porque no indica el numero de peticiones en Windows (que creo que es tu idea)...

Comment: En windows debes usar `-n` en lugar de `-c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Primero tu al realizar un ping a un cualquier host que no esta activo te va a devolver que un host es inaccesible, pero si el host responde te puede devolver "bytes" entonces desde ahí partirá nuestro script

Este es el código, ahora te explicare cada parte como funciona.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def ipRed():

    for i in range(0, 254):
        iplocal =  "192.168.1.{}".format(i)
        proceso = Popen(["ping", iplocal],  stdout=PIPE, stdin= PIPE, stderr= PIPE )
        respon = proceso.stdout.read()
        if b"bytes=32" in respon:
            print(iplocal)  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ipRed()
```

Aquí se importara el modulo subprocess que permitirá interactuar con los procesos del sistema operativo  y PIPE te permite capturar el flujo de salida y si nuestro proceso no mando ningún error

`from subprocess import PIPE, Popen`

Posteriormente se crear una función llamada ipRed

Ahora; Se creara un ciclo. Se crea una variable donde se almacenara la ip y se formateare el numero entero a string

```
for i in range(0, 254):
    iplocal =  "192.168.1.{}".format(i)
```

Se crea una variable con el metodo Popen que este metodo nos permitira abrir un proceso, se pasa como argumentos el comando, pero si el comando necesita argumentos se crea una lista, se agrega las variables y se le asigna PIPE permitira el control de flujo de proceso.

```
 proceso = Popen(["ping", iplocal],  stdout=PIPE, stdin= PIPE, stderr= PIPE )
```

Se crea una variable de respuesta que es la que contiene la respuesta de nuestro proceso.

```
respon = proceso.stdout.read()
```

Como había comentado anteriormente al realizar un ping si el host destino responde mandara "bytes" entonces, con la respuestas hacemos un condicional que si en alguna de las salidas regresa "bytes=32" entonces el host esta activo.

```
 if b"bytes=32" in respon:
            print(iplocal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta función es parte de un script que hice en mi empresa para verificar unos valores de unas estaciones que debían estar encendidas y hasta hoy día sigue funcionando. Retorna "True" si la estación hace ping, y "False" en caso contrario. Espero te sirva de orientación.

```
import subprocess

def CheckIfAliveStation(ip_address):
    # WARNING - Windows Only
    alive = False
    ping_output = subprocess.run(['ping', '-n', '1', ip_address],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if (ping_output.returncode == 0):
        if not ('unreachable' in str(ping_output.stdout)):
            alive = True
    return alive
```